# Is it necessary to delete dialog window pointer in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt

I use this code:

```
MyDialog *md = new MyDialog();
md -> show();
```

to open a dialog window in Qt. Will `md` be deleted automatically when the dialog window is closed or do I need to run `delete md` when the window is finished?

Comment: It will not delete automatically. You need to delete it yourself if necessary.

Comment: If appropriate, don't use new at all. `MyDialog md;` will create a dialog object and automatically destroy it when the variable goes out of scope. Depending how long you want it to live for, this may not be appropriate for you. In which case use smart pointers. Eg `std::unique_ptr<MyDialog> md(new MyDialog());`

Comment: @Neil although it's a good idea in general to use smart pointers, it's not the case for Qt, as it usually handles its `QWidget`s' memory in a parent-child chain cleanup manner.

Comment: The correct QT way to do it is to do the `= new myDialog( this )` or equivalent.
This is in order to avoid deleting it. See also Luliu's answer

Comment: @rubenvb Thanks I didn't know that, didn't spot the qt tag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. Unless you pass `this` while `this` is a `QWidget` or any other `QWidget`:

```
MyDialog *md = new MyDialog(this);
md->show();
```

you need to:

```
delete md;
```

at some point in order to release its memory. Also you need to make sure in this case that the [object tree](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/objecttrees.html) is well linked. What you can also do is call `setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose);` on `md` so that when you close the dialog, its memory will also be released as `Zlatomir` said. However if you need `md` to live after it was closed `setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose);` is not an option. This is also dangerous and could lead to access violation/segmentation fault if you are not careful.

Comment: To clarify, not only `this` - any widget parent counts.

Comment: @AndrewMedico You are right. But then you need also to make sure that that parent is also getting deleted sometime. I will edit.

Comment: This is just a repost of the other answer.

Comment: @Ben please check the timestamps of the two answers

Answer (score 12):

In your little piece of code you need to delete it, because it doesn't have a parent, if you set a parent, the parent will delete it's children and you only need to delete the "main-window" (the window that doesn't have a parent).

Also for QWidget derived classes you can use the: `Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose` flag and then the memory will be deallocated when the widget closes, see the documentation [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qwidget.html#close)
Then code will become:

```
MyDialog *md = new MyDialog();
md->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose);
md->show();
```